# regex for multi-delimiter string in hive serde

Tags: java, regex, hive

I use serde to read data with specific format with delimiter `||`, and trible pipes like `|||` will never appear in my data string.

One line of my data may looks loke: `aaa||bbb||ccc||ddd`, and I create the hive table as below:

```
CREATE TABLE test_log(
host STRING,
identity STRING,
user STRING,
time STRING)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
"input.regex" = "([^\\|]*)\\|{2}([^\\|]*)\\|{2}([^\\|]*)\\|{2}([^\\|]*)",
"output.format.string" = "%1$s %2$s %3$s %4$s")
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

It seems fine to read the data, but obviously the `input.regex` is not completely correct, when face some data like: `a|bc||edf||g|g||ghi`. I tried to find help in the book "Mastering Regular Expressions" but it didn't work.

Is it possible to read and extract data in the format above just with a specific `input.regex`?

Answer (score 1):

Now you capture only groups which are separated by pipe pairs, but do not contain pipe characters themselfs: `([^\\|]*)`. If you change this to `((?:[^\\|]+\\|)*[^\\|]+)` then every group will be able to contain single pipes somewhere in the middle (like `a|bc` or `gg|g`), but won't be allowed to start or end with a pipe, since this would cause ambiguity (for example: `ab|||cd` could be separated either into `ab|` and `cd` or into `ab` and `|cd`).

Answer (score 1):

It seems I've found a solution using [regex look around](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

For data like `"a|b|c||d|e|f||g|h|i"`, I can read the string with

`"input.regex" = "(.*)(?=\\|\\|)\\|{2}(.*)(?=\\|\\|)\\|{2}(.*)"`

It works fine and the pattern is clearly.